# Not enough digital outputs for SPI slave select lines (CS#)

Tags: microcontroller, spi

I have a microcontroller with only 4 digital outputs available and 4 digital inputs. The problem is that I need to communicate with at least 4 SPI devices (ADC's and DAC's). 4 SPI devices means 2 outputs on the microcontroller (MOSI,SCLK) and 1 CS per device => total of 6 microcontroller outputs.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Search for SPI Expender on digikey. http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?keywords=spi%20expender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 4 to 16 decoder.  you could drive the logic from an extra I/O pin to get 8 instead of 4.

Actually, I would probably use a SPI based shift-register to just do the CS selection, and then MUX that with the control line.  You are extremely pin limited, so you have SCLK/MOSI/CS.   You could use that last output pin to serially select which "CS" logic you will use when the actual CS goes low.

Comment: Thanks for yout help. Just thought of that: i can use a 2 to 4 decoder and use this a   chip select with the input wired to ground and the code done by the microcontroller giving me 4 CS => perfect.

Comment: I trust you are constrained to this micro for a good reason? If you are trying to save cost you just undid it with new parts.

Comment: yes i'm trying to do an extension card for a cnc machine and i don't want to redo the already existing hardware which is working fine. I agree that redoing all the card with a bigger micro would be a better option for the long run.